# Clear Cache or Clear javascript variables on Phonegap application after ajax complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, ajax, cordova

I created a Android App using Phonegap, jquery and Kendo UI. Also i have a multiple ajax request.

Now on my application i have a create invoice ajax request which uses PUT in adding data to my Rest service. Everything works when if i already created a transaction ( invoice ) and try to create another one the quantity doesn't reverts back to 1 and it doesn't create a new Transaction but only returns the last transaction i created ( NOTE: it calls the Success callback from my ajax ).

My question is how can i clear the cache on android without exiting the app.

## update

i discovered that when i successfully create an invoice after that the variables are still filled with data stored from the previous transaction. So how can i somehow reset everything to allow new data. i addded this `location.reload(true);` but would like to find another solution regarding this problem. thank you.

Comment: anyone? any ideas with regards to this matter?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a very similar problem when testing the example ToDo backbone.js application in the [Developing Backbone.js Applications book by Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/) using Cordova (PhoneGap) and running it on an Android 2.3 emulator.

The problem that I was having was that the first GET or PUTs to a particular URL were being made, but subsequent requests or updates to the same model instance (i.e. same URL) were not sent to the RESTful server, even though the jQuery.ajax calls were returning success.

The issue turned out to be an issue with the Android browser in Android 2.3 not passing on subsequent requests to the same URL. After finding confirmation here: http://jorgenmodin.net/index_html/jquery-and-android-2.3-calling-a-url-again-gives-the-cached-result 
I ended up modifying the backbone model and collection url: functions to append a unique timestamp to the URL's. This made each URL unique and then the browser made the ajax request every time as originally desired.

Here is an extract of the code that I used for the collection:

```
var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

   // Reference to this collection's model.
   model: app.Todo,

   urlRoot: 'http://<RESTful_server_address_goes_here>/todos/',

   url: function() {
       var base = _.result(this, 'urlRoot') || urlError();
       var ts = new Date().getTime();
       // Make sure that there is a trailing slash on the url, and add a timestamp
       return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) === '/' ? '' : '/') + '?_' + ts;
   },

   ...
});
```

And here an extract of the code for the model:

```
  app.Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({

      url: function() {
          var base = _.result(this.collection, 'urlRoot') || urlError();
          // if not creating a new item, then append the item id
          if (!this.isNew()) base = base + 
                               (base.charAt(base.length - 1) === '/' ? '' : '/') + 
                               encodeURIComponent(this.id);
          // now append a timestamp
          var ts = new Date().getTime();
          return base + '?_' + ts;
      },

      ...
  });
```

Note that, amongst the many things that I tried before coming up with this solution, was simply to set the jQuery.ajax cache (see jQuery.ajax documentation) to **false** in an override for backbone.sync, but this DOES NOT WORK. Here is the code anyway:

```
app.sync = function(method, model, options) {

          // THIS DOES NOT FIX THE PROBLEM !!
          // IT ONLY PREVENTS CACHING ON GET OPERATIONS 
          // HOWEVER PUT OPERATIONS ARE STILL CACHED BY ANDROID 2.3 BROWSER!!
          options.cache = false;

      return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);  

};
```